# How to replace some specific content (of various lines) of a file with the command sed?

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

I would like to know how to replace this:

```css
.otros{
   position: fixed;
   top: 116px;
   z-index: 100;
   left: 0;
}
```

by this:

```css
.otros{
   position: fixed;
   top: 70%;
   z-index: 100;
   left: 0;
}
```

The content of the file is similar to the following:

```css
.social a:not(:hover){
    width: 70px;
    -webkit-transition: 600ms;
    -o-transition: 600ms;
    -ms-transition: 600ms;
}
.social div a:not(:hover){
    width:200%;
}
.otros{
    position: fixed;
    top: 116px;
    z-index: 100;
    left: 0;
}
```

This command doesn't work:

```
sed 's/.otros{\ntop*:*;\n}/.otros{\ntop:70%;\n}/g' estilos.css
```

The result is:

```css
.social a:not(:hover){
    width: 70px;
    -webkit-transition: 600ms;
    -o-transition: 600ms;
    -ms-transition: 600ms;
}
.social div a:not(:hover){
    width:200%;
}
.otros{
    position: fixed;
    top: 116px;
    z-index: 100;
    left: 0;
}
```

How to replace specific lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sed replacement operates on individual lines by default; to perform a match in a multiline context you will need to use the `N` command to read additional lines into the pattern space. Ex.:

```
$ sed '/\.otros{/ {N;N;s/top: 116px/top: 70%/}' estilos.css 
  .social a:not(:hover){
    width: 70px;
    -webkit-transition: 600ms;
    -o-transition: 600ms;
    -ms-transition: 600ms;
  }
  .social div a:not(:hover){
    width:200%;
  }
  .otros{
    position: fixed;
    top: 70%;
    z-index: 100;
    left: 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The following *Perl* script matches everything between the `.otros{` line and the `top:` line and replaces the `top:` line by `top: 70%;`:

```
perl -pe 's/(?!\.otros\{[\w\d\s:;\-%]*)top:.*/top: 70%;/' estilos.css
```

If the lines between the `.otros{` line and the `top:` line contain anything else than:

- lowercase letters, uppercase letters, underscores (`\w`)
- numbers (`\d`)
- whitespace (`\s`)
- colon (`:`)
- semicolon (`;`)
- dash (`\-`)
- percent symbol (`%`)

just add it between the square brackets (`[]`).

The result is:

```css
.social a:not(:hover){
    width: 70px;
    -webkit-transition: 600ms;
    -o-transition: 600ms;
    -ms-transition: 600ms;
}
.social div a:not(:hover){
    width:200%;
}
.otros{
    position: fixed;
    top: 70%;
    z-index: 100;
    left: 0;
}
```

**Note:** This script does not replace `top: 116px;` only, but everything after `top:` (`top:.*`) inside `.otros`. For example, it would also replace `top: 55px;` or `top: 90%;`.

If you just need to replace `top: 116px;`, then the command would be this:

```
perl -pe 's/(?!\.otros\{[a-zA-Z0-9\s:;\-%]*)top: 116px;/top: 70%;/' estilos.css
```